# LINQ to entities (Create a new table, display all tables from a database)

Tags: c#, database, linq, linq-to-entities

I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours now, and no amount og Google search
has yielded anything usefull, I'm currently studying up on my exam and I believe i will need to know these things, so i hope someone can help me!

I have two questions;

1. Is it not possible to create a new table? (Or Entity i believe it is called)
2. And also, is it possible to display all table's you have?

I'm making a small forms project where I'm basically just making methods that will carry out the different commands that Linq to Entity proves.

Such as a a controle to create a new table with the name put in the textbox,
a listbox displaying all tables in the database and so on.

Hopefully someone will be able to help.

~Etarnalazure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: no, list MOST ORM's it is a data access technology. EntityFramework has schema updates etc., but again this is not "runtime".

2: no, again, this is not a technology to manage databases. YOu only can query what you have classes for.

Well, 2 IS possible, but you have to generate the classes in a separate appdomain at runtime, then use that to query for data.

Comment: Darn.. I figured I'd make a second table that gets updated with the names of the new tables I would create in runtime... Well, this is annoying.. Thanks for the fast response though!

Comment: Most ORM's are in this area. You can partially work around it - but fully dynamic access is the area where dataset and such solutions shine.

Comment: I havent worked with much other then MySQL. But i guess, it would be good if i read up on datasets.